# RecyclerView pushed up when keyboard is launched - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have an android app where the main activity contains a recyclerView and a fab in the bottom right corner. When the user clicks on the fab,an alert dialog opens.

The alert dialog has several edit text,which takes input from the user. So,the keyboard is launched when the user clicks on the editText. As soon as the keyboard opens,the recylerView items move up in the background of alert dialog.  I don't want the items to go up in the background since they overlap with the heading. My recyclerView is constrained from all 4 sides. Also when keyboard is dismissed,the items come back to their position

How do I fix this?

Comment: First thing, share you code, how are we supposed to help? Second, Check the option `windowSoftInputMode` in manifest's activity tag, if it's not adjustPan, set it else share your manifest as well.

Comment: Thanks! it was not set to adjustPan. I added it, and it worked. If you want you can write it as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Glad, it helped.